# Is isolation always required in a 4-20mA current loop circuit?

Tags: isolation, 4-20ma

When designing a 4-20mA output circuit, is it always advisable to isolate the output circuitry?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are designing something like a general-purpose high performance thermocouple transmitter, even if it's a two-wire type.

There are plenty of cases where it's not necessary though, and if it's not necessary it may not even be desirable for cost, or other, reasons.

But isolation is usually a good thing from a noise perspective. So "advisable" may be a safe perspective for a consulting engineer.

It should be noted that there may be zero, one, or two isolation barriers in a transmitter, in general (for power and for signal). Two wire transmitters have zero or one.

Comment: We had controllers that were put into industrial environments (user install) that would connect to additional building controllers. Sometimes they would cause a ground loop and the weird issues that go along with those.  The only sure fire method to solve it without rewiring the building was to use 4-20 isolators.  Expensive, but cheaper than an electrician capable of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

> *When designing a 4-20mA output circuit is it \$\color{red}{\text{always}}\$ advisable to
> isolate the output circuitry?*

No, it isn't. Most 4-20 mA devices receive their power from the current loop and therefore to try and isolate anything would be a complete hindrance.

Comment: @Aaron please post that comment under the question and note that comments that are mini-answers are generally not preferred. Does your comment bring anything to my answer - I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for a regulated current source loop is to make the signal high impedance and thus reject common-mode H-field (current) and E-field voltage coupling by parasitic inductance and capacitance.

**In some extreme cases, an optoisolator provides additional isolation due to low pF coupling.** For a linear signal this must be the dual detector type with the single LED and external Op Amp linear negative feedback circuit to correct for LED nonlinearity.

Common-Mode Rejection-Ratio, CMRR is a measurement to verify improvement in signal/noise ratio, SNR due to balance error tolerance.  Laser trimmed Instrument Amps have about 120 dB CMRR which is a tolerance of 1 part per million is near ideal but the actual CMRR is the worst-case imbalance in the entire signal path.  The actual CMRR is the worst case of the cable CMRR wire pair imbalance and optional optocoupler vs. frequency and amplitude of the interference.

- Low-frequency line coupled line CM noise may be> 60 dB high than your signal and can be rejected with standard CC current loops.  If there is arc noise or close proximity, isolation or cable orientation helps.

\$\text{CMRR}(f) = 20 log \dfrac{\Delta V_{diff}(f)}{\Delta V_{CM}(f)}\$

### Additional reading mat'l

https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-4387EN   (opto)
https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/what-you-need-to-know-about-cmrr-the-operational-amplifier-part-1